Does linear operator of range $n \in \Bbb{N}$ conserve inner product?

Let $H_1, H_2$ be Hilbert spaces and $T \in \mathcal{L} (H_1, H_2)$ such that $\dim T(H_1) = n \in \Bbb{N}$ . There exists $\{x_k\}_{k=1}^n \subset H_1$ and $\{y_k\}_{k=1}^n \subset H_2$ such that for all $x \in H_1$ we have $$Tx = \sum_{k=1}^n \langle x, x_k \rangle y_k$$

I am trying to prove this result in order to use it for another. Since $\dim T(H_1) = n \in \Bbb{N}$, there exists $\{y_k\}_{k=1}^n$ orthonormal basis of $T(H_1)$, and so there is $\{x_k\}_{k=1}^n \subset H_1$ such that for all $k \in [1, n] \cap \Bbb{Z}: Tx_k = y_k$ . Since $\{y_k\}_{k=1}^n$ is orthonormal basis, for all $x \in H_1$ there is $\{ \lambda_j \}_{j=1}^n \subset \Bbb{K}$ such that $Tx = \sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j y_j$ and therefore for all $k \in [1, n] \cap \Bbb{Z}: \lambda_k = \langle Tx , y_k \rangle = \langle Tx , Tx_k \rangle$ .
My intuition says that there should be a way to prove that $T$ conserves the inner product and so $\langle Tx , Tx_k \rangle = \langle x, x_k \rangle$ finishing the proof, but I am struggling on how to prove it, so any possible help would be appreciated.

Let ${y_k}$ be orthornormal, spanning $T(H_1)$, and let $x_i = T^* y_i$.

@TheoBendit Thanks a lot!
